# How do I create an API that counts the number of records containing my search criteria with data that's in JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I'm running Python 3.9 in a Jupyter Notebook.

I'm trying to create an API that returns a count of the number of records containing my search string in the column. This column includes strings with multiple words in them, not just the term specified in the search. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOU3y.png)  in the specified column.

When I try adding .count() in different places, the API won't work.

When I ran the following attempt, I got " KeyError: 'Key Skills' "

```
api_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"

data = pd.read_json(api_url)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_number_of_jobs_T(technology):
    
    technology = df['Key Skills']
    
    payload={"Key Skills":technology}
    
    r=requests.get(api_url,params=payload)
    
    number_of_jobs=r.count()
    
    return technology,number_of_jobs
```

These also didn't work:

I tried reading JSON into pd.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzIdY.png)

Tried to read the JSON data into pd before searching for the STR, but I don't know how to search for the STR (in JSON) when it appears inside a longer string (like using %str%...where do I place % for JSON to read it?)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xj2.png)

I think I'm supposed to find and place the answer somewhere in the payload (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOU3y.png).

How do I get the API to count only the results that include my search term?
(in this example, the term goes in place of "technology", which points to column 'Key Skills')

Comment: `matching_rows = df[df['column_of_interest'].icontains('search_term')]` I guess?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is my first post on stackoverflow. Instead of voting me down, please provide better feedback for me to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this, and it works when 'technology' is called. My problem was that I wasn't including or setting 'number_of_jobs' to a defined starting INT. I also had tried to use len but wasn't setting it to loop w/ +.

```
api_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"

def get_number_of_jobs_T(technology):

    number_of_jobs = 0

    payload={"Key Skills":technology}

    r=requests.get(api_url,params=payload)

    data = r.json()

    number_of_jobs += len(data)

return technology,number_of_jobs
```